# Luks encryption not removing from Pendrive

Tags: encryption, kali-linux, tails, qubes-os

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E506.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYgoG.jpg)

When I try to install qubes Os to pWhen I try to install qubes Os to pendrive (SanDisk 64gb 3.2 gen 1) for live format while installing suddenly stopped and pendrive not showing when check partition manager it shows read-only i tried every possible way from YouTube nothing works then I found its encrypted while installing qubes, Then i checked encryption it's luks and i search about how to remove encryption i tried `cryptsetup -luks RemoveKey /dev/sda4` **I know the passphrase** *it gives output of Device wipe error, offset 32768*.

```
    root@amnesia:/home/amnesia cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sdc4

WARNING: Device /dev/sdc4 already contains a 'crypto LUKS' superblock signature.

WARNING!

This will overwrite data on /dev/sdc4 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type 'yes' in capital letters): YES

Enter passphrase for /dev/sdc4:

Verify passphrase:

Failed to open file /dev/sdc4 in read/write mode. Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).

root@amnesia:/home/amnesiae cryptsetup y v LuksFormat /dev/sdc4 WARNING: Device /dev/sdc4 already contains a crypto LUKS superblock signature.

WARNING!

This will overwrite data on /dev/sdc4 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type yes in capital letters): YES Enter passphrase for /dev/sdc4:

verify passphrase:

Failed to open file /dev/sdc4 in read/write mode.

Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).

root@amnesia:/home/amnesiae cryptsetup -y v LuksRemovekey /dev/sdc4

Enter passphrase to be deleted:

Verify passphrase:

Key slot 8 unlocked.

Keyslot is selected for deletion.

WARNING!

This is the last keyslot. Device will become unusable after purging this key

Are you sure? (Type 'yes' in capital letters): YES

Device wipe error, offset 32768. Cannot wipe device /dev/sdc4.

Key slot a removed.

Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4zhR.jpg)

Comment: To be honest, this post is a mess.  It requires too much concentration.  Please post text information as text not image. and make it concise.

Comment: Sorry for that am new to this type of site's

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is unrelated to LUKS or Qubes – it shows up because your pendrive's firmware has switched to read-only mode. If you look at the `lsblk` output, you'll see `1` in the `RO` field for the device; this almost always comes from the disk itself indicating that its medium is read-only.

This is an extremely common failure mode for pendrives that have reached their write endurance limits. (And probably for some other unknown reasons, too.)

If the `RO` flag remains at `1` after re-connecting the pendrive, there's usually nothing you can do to fix it (except maybe trying to find a manufacturer tool to low-level format the flash memory and squeeze some more life out of it).

In the unlikely case that your current OS itself has changed /dev/sdb to read-only in order to prevent persistence, you could try `blockdev --setrw /dev/sdb` to undo that. However, if the pendrive itself has switched to being read-only, this won't help at all – it'll just change the kind of errors you get. (Pay attention to the more detailed error messages in `dmesg`.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply